# UWP Get array from json Url

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I'm using a class to get data from json to my main page and in my json i have an array i want to get them to my Main Page Here's my class code

```
    class WeatherDays
{
    public async static Task<day> GetWeather(double lat, double lon)
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var responce = await http.GetAsync("http://a3ane.com/omarNasar/d.php");
        var result = await responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(day));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data = (day)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        return data;
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class Omarnasar
{
    [DataMember]
    public string w_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_note_tody { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_time { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_tody_one { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_temperature_one { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_humidity_one { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_note_one { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_tody_two { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_temperature_two { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_humidity_two { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string w_note_two { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class day
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<Omarnasar> omarnasar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my problem is i don't know how to get then to my main page using the task here's my try on MainPage

```
        day week = await WeatherDays.GetWeather(20.0, 30.0);
        temp1.Text = week.omarnasr.
```

I don't know how to use them can anyone help my !!!

Comment: Is this what you want ? `temp1.Text = String.Join(" ", week.omarnasr);`

Comment: @ravikumar i want to get `w_temperature_one` from the array and put it on `temp1.Text`

Comment: @ravikumar yes !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var obj in week.omarnasr)
    {
        sb.Append(obj.w_temperature_one + " ");
    }
    temp1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I'll try this Thanks